# Pulling content from Artifactory using Python

Tags: python, download, artifactory

I have this Artifactory link from which I want to pull EVERYTHING. I have an older version of the script with the paths hardcoded.

It only downloads files, doesn't download EVERYTHING there is. I just give it the artifactory path (hardcoded) and give it the local path where to download them (also hardcoded). I would love a more... optimal approach

This is the download function in itself:

```py
def downloadfiles(path, localpath):
    for p in path:
        head, tail = os.path.split(p)
        with p.open() as fd:
            print(p)
            with open(localpath + tail, "wb") as out:
                out.write(fd.read())
```

The path is basically: basepath + /folder1, basepath + /folder1/folder2, basepath + /folder3/folder4/folder5, basepath + /folder3/folder4/folder6 etc. It's just stupid.

Anyone has experience with artifactory and pulling files using Python and knows of a way to make this get EVERYTHING?

So I give it the basepath and it just downloads everything from there, files & folders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download all the contents of the repository in an archive, you can use the [Retrieve Folder or Repository Archive](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/retrieve-folder-or-repository-archive) API.
This can bit a bit slow on large repositories, and requires Enable Folder Download to be set.

You can also use JFrog CLI, there is more info and an example in [this KB](https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-can-i-download-folders-with-their-content-from-a-repository/artifactory-how-can-i-download-folders-with-their-content-from-a-repository).

If you want to use Python, you can update the list of files using AQL, and download them to the same path. You can use the code below to update the list of paths:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

DATA =  'items.find({"type":"file","repo":{"$eq":"<REPO_NAME>"}})'
response = requests.post('https://<JFROG_URL>/artifactory/api/search/aql', 
auth=HTTPBasicAuth('<USER>', '<PASSWORD>'), data = DATA)
data = response.json()
i=1
while i < len(data['results']):
    repo = data['results'][i]['repo']
    path = data['results'][i]['path']
    name = data['results'][i]['name']
    if path == '.':
        basepath = repo + "/" + name
    else:
        basepath = repo + "/" + path + "/" + name
    
    #This will create and append the path's to the file. If the file exists you might want to delete it before appending.
    #with open("results.txt", "a") as myfile:
        #myfile.write(basepath+"\n") 
    
    i+=1
```